# Why do I get the message "You missed the Pokémon!"

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I recently started playing Pokémon Blue again from where I left off.  I had just beaten Erika and I was off to Lavender Town to get the Poké Flute. After receiving the flute, I immediately woke up a Snorlax.

I managed to get Snorlax down to an HP level that would kill him if I landed one more move. I had no moves that would freeze, paralyze, or put Snorlax to sleep, so, naturally, I started to throw pokéballs.

On my first throw, I got the message *"You missed the pokémon!"* to which I tried again with the same result. I threw all 8 of my pokéballs with no luck.

I thought at first that Snorlax could not be caught, like the Marowak you fight before getting the Poké Flute, but it turns out, getting the message *"You missed the pokémon!"* is the same as the pokémon breaking out as explained in [this forum post.](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/198314-pokemon-yellow-version-special-pikachu-edition/49321154)

Why do I get this message as opposed to the conventional *"The Pokémon broke free"*? Could this be because Snorlax is not randomly encountered? Or does this have something to do with catch rates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal, it is just the lowest possible result of attempting to capture a Pokémon.

While in later games wild Pokémon always get inside a Poké Ball and then shake 0, 1, 2, or 3 times before breaking out, in first generation games the worst result was not getting the Pokémon in a Poké Ball at all.

Comment: Since I've never played gen 1 before, i guess i never noticed.